# Use of "Vigorous" in a sentence

Tags: word-usage

I'm editing materials for a TOEIC test and the following answer came up: "Leo is quite vigorous."  The picture shows a boy on a bicycle struggling to get up a hill.

There is a discussion in the office about "vigorous."  I looked online for usage examples and found most (if not all) were of the sort vigorous NOUN or vigorous used as an adverb.  I prefer the answer be "Leo is pedaling vigorously" or "Leo is having a vigorous workout." or something that uses "vigorous" in the way that makes sense to me.

My question: Can vigorous be used in this way?  If so, why? and if not, why not?

Comment: Where's the adverb in  "Leo is having a vigorous workout."

Comment: vig·or·ous ˈviɡ(ə)rəs/ adjective adjective: vigorous     strong, healthy, and full of energy.     synonyms: robust, healthy, hale and hearty, strong, sturdy, fit; ...     hardy, tough, athletic;     bouncing, thriving, flourishing, blooming;     energetic, lively, active, perky, spirited, vibrant, vital, zestful;     informalpeppy, bouncy, in the pink     "the child was vigorous"     antonyms: weak, frail         characterized by or involving physical strength, effort, or energy.         "vigorous aerobic exercise"         (of language) forceful. "a vigorous denial"         ... ... (Google)

Comment: @Kris None, I just wanted to give an example as an adverb or attributive.

Comment: "Before dawn he had slept for a few hours, and refreshed, vigorous, and in good spirits, he mounted his horse and rode out into the field in that happy mood in which everything seems possible and everything succeeds." Read more at http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/vigorous

Comment: @Kris I understand the definition, I'm just not sure that it is best to use it for a person or if it can be used in a sentence such as X is vigorous.  That's why I'm asking, because "sounds wrong to my ear" isn't good enough when editing material and I'd like some more ears.

Comment: "He looks very vigorous, considering his age." http://www.manythings.org/sentences/words/vigorous/1.html

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with the example.  The principle definition of *vigorous* is as an adjective.

Comment: @Kris - You got me!

Answer (score 2):

As to [attributive vs. predicative](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/words/attributive-and-predicative-adjectives-american) use of *vigorous*, both are possible:

> African dance is **vigorous**, but full of subtlety.
>   Sir Robert was a strong and **vigorous** politician.

[[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/vigorous)]

The examples also show that *vigorous* can describe a person (as opposed to activity etc.) The only reservation I have is that, used of a person, it seems to convey their overall temperament, rather than their momentary effort. That is why `*Leo is quite vigorous.*' sounds somewhat odd to me as a rendering of a picture of someone undertaking a strenuous activity.

Comment: yes, it seems odd to me as well.  As a temporary solution we are going with "Leo is quite robust."  Means having to make changes on several pages, though...something I feel is worth the effort, but just want to make sure I'm correct in my feeling.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use ***[vigorous](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/vigorous)*** with the connotation you are suggesting:

> very active, determined or full of energy
>   (synonym energetic)
>
> - *a vigorous campaign against tax fraud*
> - *a vigorous opponent of the government*
> - *take vigorous exercise for several hours a week.*

OLD

The term is a very old one:

[Vigorous](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=vigorous):

> - c. 1300 (early 13c. as a surname), ***from Anglo-French vigrus, Old French vigoros "strong, robust, powerful"***  (12c., Modern French vigoreux), from Medieval Latin vigorosus, from Latin vigere "be lively, flourish, thrive" (see vigor).

Etymonline

Comment: so for you "Leo is quite vigorous.' is ok?

Comment: Yes, depending on the meaning you want to convey:  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=quite+vigorous&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cquite%20vigorous%3B%2Cc0

Comment: He doesn't like them, so what. I have deleted my answer because it needs reorganisation. But I'll undelete it. The bounty... hmm.. still haven't made my mind up what to do.